# Edit "app" attribute of xml element

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I got following problem:
I'm currently developing a sensor app and I'd like to check if the sensors are available or not. If they aren't, I want to change the color of a button (which starts an activity where the value of the sensor is being displayed) to grey.
Sadly, I can't just change the background color of the button because I'm using the Circle Button Library by Markushi.
This button looks like this:

```
<at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gyroscope"
            app:cb_color="@color/colorMain"
            app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dip"
            android:id="@+id/gyroscope"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/temperature"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/temperature"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>
```

As you can see this attribute defines the color.

```
app:cb_color="@color/colorMain"
```

My Question is: How can I change this color programmaticly in this method?

```
public void testSensors() {
    if (testManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE) == null) {

    }
}
```

EDIT:
setColor doesn't really work. There is this border left. ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRyBo.png))
Also: I'm using #616161 as the new color.

EDIT2:
Found out, that the border is caused by the transparent circle thing which gets bigger, when the button is pressed. So basically removing this circle thing will be fine. I try to find an answer on my own :)

Comment: then you wont have the animation if you remove the circle right?

Comment: I don't really need the animation. So I could get rid of it. I'll try it :)

Comment: @Bhargav That's it! .setAnimationProgress(100) seems to disable the Circle! Thanks so much!

Comment: This is why you shouldn't be using deprecated github projects, why not just use the damn FloatingActionButton from the design lib?

Comment: @Bhargav Well, i could have used that. (Might change the design anyways) But i thought: "That's not the common use of the FAB" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CircleButton button;

button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId);


public void testSensors() {
    if (testManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE) == null) {
         button.setColor(Color.parse("#000000"));
    }
}
```

If you are using normal `button` then

```
button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent));
```

You can use

1) `Color.parse("#000000")`

2) `ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.yourColor)`

Comment: he already tried the `setBackgroundColor` and he doesn't like it. Plus if you read the source code the circleButton here extends an imageview, so the setbackgroundColor doesnt really work in this case.

Comment: Doesn't really work aswell. (See my new answer somewhere on this page)

Comment: @2Simpel ok Good Best Wishes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setColor()` method of the circleButton, as you can see from the [source code here](https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton/blob/master/library/src/main/java/at/markushi/ui/CircleButton.java#L92) .

So basically what you need to do is get a reference to your circle Button, using the `findViewById` method of your activity. then

```
public void testSensors() {
    if (testManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE) == null) {
        myCircleButton.setColor(Color.parse("#000000"));
    }
}
```

Also if you are seeing the pressed ring, then that means the state of the button is somehow in the pressed state, so try setting it o false using the `setPressed(false)` method.

Comment: Doesn't really work aswell. (See my new answer somewhere around here)

Comment: @2Simpel try setting pressed as false, with `cb.setPressed(false)`

Comment: Sorry. Doesn't work... (Driving me crazy...) But i found out that I have to get rid of the little transparent "border" which gets bigger when pressed. In the question at the top I added a few things and an image. This is what it looks like right now. But anyway. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer this problem (if anyone has the same):
You can set the animation to 100. This somehow disables the circle.
For some reason the color of the button has now a fixed color (dark grey) but scince this is fine to me and I don't want to cry under my table, I just let it be and move on with my project.

```
mCircleButton.setAnimationProgress(100);
```

Thank you all so much for your help! :)